# Which iwlwifi firmware for Intel WiFi Link 5100?

Tags: 13.04, intel-wireless, firmware

After upgrading to 13.04 the wifi usually fails to find a network and after a while the network manager crashes. After some digging it looks like the iwlwifi firmware version for my PC Intel WiFi Link 5100 adapter is wrong.

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

shows that

```
[...]
description: Wireless interface
product: WiFi Link 5100
vendor: Intel Corporation  
[...]
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-21-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.0.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

but according to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi the Intel® Wireless WiFi 5100AGN driver should be iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11.tar.gz (the firmware=8.83.5.1 above refers to an other wifi device namely to Intel® Wireless WiFi 5350AGN).

Why does 13.04 use iwlwifi firmware=8.83.5.1 and not firmware=5.4.1.16 as suggested at http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi ?

In order to correct the situation I downloaded the iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11.tar.gz which contains a file iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode. I also removed existing  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi* files (e.g. iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode) and copied the new iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode in the firmware directory

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/*iwlwifi* ~/keep_iwlwif
sudo cp iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode /lib/firmware
```

After rebooting sudo lshw -class network displayed the firmware=5.4.1.16 which seemed good to me but the dmesg displayed following iwlwifi errors.

```
[   14.196502] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode' failed.
[   14.200629] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-4.ucode' failed.
[   14.204814] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-3.ucode' failed.
[   14.253843] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode' failed.
```

I decided to add the iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode back to /lib/firmware and rebooted. After reboot I was back in where I started, sudo lshw -class network displayed again the firmware=8.83.5.1 and no dmesg errors for iwlwifi. Moreover, the wifi didn't work any better.

Comment: Did it work correctly with the `iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode`?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean much. After the 13.04 upgrade the wifi has worked every now and then. So, I can not say whether this time it was by iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode or by chanche.

Comment: Also same hardware but no problem.                              *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-21-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn

Comment: I think it's not the firmware fault. Hope help you to figure it out.

Comment: Probably it was not a firmware fault. I installed a new 13.04 64bit and it seems to have the same firmware files, iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode in /lib/firmware while the sudo lshw -class network displays firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 in use. That seems a bit strange to me as well as the fact that the iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11.tar.gz which is supposed to contain the newest version contains a file  iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode.    But, what is important is that now the wifi works.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same wireless card and downloaded the iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1.tgz) and added that to the lib/firmware director and its working well. I'm using an Intel Galileo board with Yachto Linux build on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found some may be temporary solution. For now wifi is more stable and have only one traffic stop without disconnecting. Use recommended firmware and rename it to iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode . You will see complain in dmesg but anyway it works:

```
Firmware has old API version, expected v5, got v1.
[   18.595062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: New firmware can be obtained from http://www.intellinuxwireless.org/.
[   18.595065] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 5.4.1.16
```